# How does Ucommerce display marketing campaigns in Sitecore?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-ucommerce

I created three marketing campaigns, two of them are being displayed on all pages, while the third one is displayed with others on the product pages only. This is how I display campaigns in C# code:

```
var campaignItems = MarketingLibrary.GetTargetedCampaignItems();
```

Ucommerce does it correctly, but I want to know how Ucommerce knows that two campaigns are for all pages and that one is only for the product page, and control it through my C# code.

I use **Sitecore 8.2**

[image]

[image]